# how to watch video from youtube by wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my wp7 app, I get an url from some source, and then try to play it in webBrowser.

```
Video_Browser.Navigate(new Uri(uri));
```

uri looks like

http://www.youtube.com/embed/tFYAC2YuDv0

on desktop I can open it by Chrome, and see full size the video, but in emulator its only the black screen(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/5-how-to-use-mediaplayerlauncher-in-a-wp7-app), the emulator just can't render video.  I think your code is probably correct, but you'll need to run it on an actual phone to test it.